# Is it possible to send mail using only react?

Tags: reactjs, email, nobackend

I have an app that is built only using react. It does not have a backend. Is it possible to send an email just from the react front end itself? Is there an api that would allow me to do that?

If this is not possible, all I really need to do is store data from a form somewhere I can access later. Is there an api that would allow me to do that without any backend using only react? Any help is really appreciated! Thanks in advance!

Comment: Be careful when using front-end only. You will need to put some credentials in the code and they will be visible in the browser (Developer Tools). A back-end will hide that. Something like Azure Functions may solve your problem for free.

Answer (score 5):

React have nothing to do with sending emails because after all it is a library that provides ability to render UI, nothing more.

However you can send emails from client side by using any API that is available over internet, for example you can take a look at [Gmail API](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/).

Answer (score 0):

ReactJs is a framework that is used to develop the user interface.There is no way to send the email by using Reactjs because email need server for that you can use Nodejs.
Although, Gmail API is there to send an email.